# Understanding epsilon closure algorithm pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, finite-automata, dfa, nfa

The following pseudocode is from *Introduction to Compiler Construction in a Java World* book. This algorithm is supposed to output the epsilon closure of a set of a states of a nondeterministic finite machine (to convert it to a deterministic one eventually).

```
# Input: a set of states, S
# Output: epsilon_closure(S)

    Stack P.addAll(S) #a stack containing all states in S
    Set C.addAll(S)   #the closure initially contains the states in S

    while ! P.empty() do
         s = P.pop()
         for r in m(s, epsilon) do
            # m(s, epsilon) is a set of states
            if r not in C then
                P.push(r)
                C.add(r)
            end if
        end for

    end while
    return C
```

I know what epsilon closure is but unfortunately I'm having a hard time to understand how this code works.

Note: `m()` in the code is the transition function of the machine.

Answer (score -2):

It just applies the transition function to each state in S. The states resulting from that application are collected in C. Once you've finished looking at each state in P, C contains the epsilon closure.

Note that the input S is not necessarily the complete set of states in the NFA, so that the intersection of S and m(s, epsilon) may not be empty.

Comment: is `C` an array? Isn't it already filled with all the states from the begining (`C.addAll(S)`)? If so, how `r not in C` will ever be true?

Comment: `S` is a subset of the states of the NFA, not necessarily the set of all states.

Comment: It's terse because there isn't that much going on. What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: Would be nice to mention what S is, why you have to find C in the subset construction algorithm, and how transitive closure works.  I don't think OP knows these things